# MongoDB - Sort collection by amount of fields with same value

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, backend

I have a unsorted collection like this:

**_id | name**

```
1 | Michael

2 | Tobias

3 | John

4 | Michael

5 | Tobias

6 | Michael
```

I would like to sort this collection by the number of same values for "name".

So it should look like this:

**_id | name**

```
1 | Michael

4 | Michael

6 | Michael

2 | Tobias

5 | Tobias

3 | John
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
Model.find({}).sort({ name: 'asc'})
```

OR

```
Model.find({}).sort({ name: 1 })
```

OR

it can also be used with findOne too.

`Model.findOne({condition comes here}).sort({ name: 1 })`

OR For Aggregation

```
Model.aggregate(
   [
     { $sort : { name: 1 } }
   ]
)
```

and here is the [reference](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) for aggregation.

Comment: updated the answer, please check and approve the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This needs an aggregation query, as follows.The `$group` gets the documents grouped by name and their count. The`$sort` puts them by descending order of the `count`. The `$unwind` ungroups the earlier grouped documents. The `$project` and `$replaceRoot` stages are for shaping the document into the original form.

```
db.names.aggregate( [
  { $group: { _id: "$name", count: { $sum: 1 }, doc: { $push: "$$ROOT"} } },
  { $sort: { count: -1 } },
  { $project: { doc: 1, _id: 0 } },
  { $unwind: "$doc" },
  { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$doc" } }
] )
```

Comment: In the above query, the `$project` stage is not necessary.